# How can I flatten a set of text data in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I am using PowerBI to display a set of activities. For example, we capture when we send an invitation, whether is was opened, accepted, and attended. The data comes in with one line per activity, like:

| Name | Activity |
| --- | --- |
| JP Jones | Invitation Sent |
| JP Jones | Invitation Opened |
| JP Jones | Invitation Accepted |

I've converted the Activity into a True/False

```
EventIsAccepted = IF ( [Activity] = "Invitation Accepted", "True", "False"
)
```

The functions work fine, but the output still displays all three lines and I can't collapse them. I can see why this isn't working, but can't think of a way around it.

EDIT:

My current output looks like this:

[image: output with 3 lines]

I'd like to have it look like this:

[image: output with 1 line]

Comment: Can you share a .pbix and clarify your desired result?

Comment: Since it pull from a table, will you be able to use a .pbix? I'll edit my question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me.

[image]

```
EventIsAccepted = IF ( "Invitation Accepted" IN  VALUES('Table'[Activity]),   "True", "False"
)
```