# PowerBI Flatten a set of text for multiple records

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I asked a similar question yesterday (link below) and approved it too soon. I wasn't clear enough in my question and only got some of the answer. In PowerBI, I want to flatten several rows of text data into one line. This is a continuation of my question below. Also, I had a bug in my revised code and should not have accepted the answer and decided to just start a new question.

[Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77259582/how-can-i-flatten-a-set-of-text-data-in-powerbi)

Here is a data sample.

| Name | Activity |
| --- | --- |
| JP Jones | Invitation Sent |
| JP Jones | Invitation Opened |
| JP Jones | Invitation Accepted |
| Drake | Invitation Sent |
| Drake | Invitation Opened |
| Drake | Invitation Accepted |
| Drake | Event Attended |
| P Cline | Invitation Sent |

This is the output I'd like to see:

[image]

My code looks like this (thanks [@Davide Bacci](https://user:18345037) for this bit of code). I'm only showing one of the columns but it's repeated for all 4.

`EventAttended = IF ( "Event Attended" IN  VALUES (Query1[Activity]), "True","False")`

My output looks like this:

[image: Incorrect output showing all True values]

Answer (score 0):

To get your desired result you can pivot your table:

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Count", each 1, type number),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Added Custom", List.Distinct(#"Added Custom"[Activity]), "Activity", "Count", List.Sum)
```

I created the `Count` column so that u can group by `Name`.

The complete code is :

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45W8gpQ8MrPSy1W0lHyzCvLLEksyczPUwhOzStRitXBJe1fkJqXmoJHgWNycmpBCVSJS1FidioO87HIIRmORRarya5lQPMUHEtKUvNSoFIBCs45mXlYrY0FAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Name = _t, Activity = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Activity", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Count", each 1, type number),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Added Custom", List.Distinct(#"Added Custom"[Activity]), "Activity", "Count", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

You should have something  like this:
[image: screenshot]

You can now adapt data as you like (null as false and 1 as true)

Hope this helps

Comment: I've never done the type of transformation you suggest. Where would I put this code? Is this a new column or (I suspect) transforming all the data. Also, there are ~50 columns in the table. Does that affect it at all?

Comment: This type of transformation is done on M query, you can find it when you right clic your table and then choose edit query, in ribon on top find Advenced editor, there you can find your source and all the steps applied

Comment: I'm getting an error that says Token Identifier Expected and points to the let_t code.

My source is a database table and the query looks like this:

let
    Source = Sql.Database("MyServer", "MyDB", [Query="SELECT * FROM MyTable"]), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Name = _t, Activity = _t]),

Comment: then you can change it like follows : 
let 
 Source = Sql.Database("MyServer", "MyDB", [Query="SELECT * FROM MyTable"]),
        #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source , "Count", each 1, type number),
        #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Added Custom", List.Distinct(#"Added Custom"[Activity]), "Activity", "Count", List.Sum)
 in 
        #"Pivoted Column"

Comment: It has a different error now: This query contains transformations that can't be used for DirectQuery. Thanks.

Comment: If you're in DirectQuery, i don't think it's doable in PowerBI, but you can do directly in a SQL query

Comment: That was my backup plan. Thanks!